# Prove the continuity of m (Lebesgue measure)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \cdots$ be a countable collection of measurable sets.  Then 
$$
m\!\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right) = \lim_{k\to\infty} m(A_k)
$$

I think that the way to prove this is to pass from nested sets to the union of disjoint sets and then use countable additivity, but I'm getting lost in the details.  I've been told to take the case where $m(A_k) = \infty$, but I don't see why this needs to be done separately.

Comment: That sounds like a good start. This is a follow-your-nose kind of proof. You really would be robbing yourself to not struggle with it and find it for yourself.

Comment: I’ve just suggested an edit to your question to better format MathJax. If you’d like, here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). The main thing is to use `\left` and `\right` to automatically resize delimiters, to use `\bigcup` when the union is not a binary operation, and to use ` \ ` before upright functions like $\limsup$, $\log$ and $\sin$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_k=A_k\backslash A_{k-1},\ A=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$. Since $\{C_k\}$ are disjoint (and measurable):
$$\mu(A)=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(C_k)$$
If the sum is finite, we can deduce that $\mu(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty C_k)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. But $\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty C_k=A\backslash A_{n-1}$, so
$$\mu(A)=\mu(A\backslash A_n)+\mu(A_n)\underset{n\to\infty}{\to}\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)$$
When the sum is not finite, conclude is easy.

Comment: how did you get that $\mu(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty C_k)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: I don't think you need to consider cases. The proof goes through fine as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set $C_1=A_1$ and $C_k=A_k\backslash A_{k-1}$ for $n\ge 2.$

The $C_k$ are pairwise disjoint, $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty C_k,\ $ and $ A_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^n C_k.$

We have then

$\tag1\mu(A)=\mu (\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty C_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(C_k)$

and also

$\tag2\mu(A_n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu(C_k)$

so finally,

$\tag3 \lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(A_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu(C_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(C_k)=\mu(A)$